# Chrome / Chromium touch issue (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, chromium, touchscreen

I'm having an issue with Google Chrome, more specifically with touch scrolling (drag and drop style) on few MSI All -in - One computers.

I'm using three models of these kind of computers - the joke is it's actually working on two types of them (MSI Pro 16B Flex, AP1622ET-226XEU) but it doesn't work at AP1622ET-037XEU.

It's doesn't make sense, because I've already updated the touch driver to the newest one - they use same eGalaxTouch pointing input device, also they're both working working on same version of system, same version of Chrome (newest in repo). Chrome://flags options are set to same values. I've already tried with --touch-devices start option.

I've already searched forum for walkaround for this issue, but none of them solved my problem.

If anybody could help - I'd be grateful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

First of all,

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Paste

```
usbtouchscreen

usbhid
```

Right after lp, then load modules (only at 1st time) by command

```
sudo modprobe usbtouchscreen usbhid
```

Right after that, you have to download and extract eGalax Touch driver (you have to choose compatibile driver with your kernel version; check it by:

```
uname -r
```

Open terminal in folder you extracted the driver, then

```
sudo sh setup.sh
```

After that you get prompted you have to reboot, so: 
`reboot` or `systemctl reboot -i`

Next step to do is to edit SystemD service:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full eGTouch.service
```

Overwrite the code with this one below:

```
 # eGalax Touchscreen service file

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/usr/bin/eGTouchD
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
After=apparmor.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
TimeoutSec=0
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=no
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/eGTouchD start
ExecReload=/usr/bin/eGTouchD restart
ExecStop=/usr/bin/eGTouchD stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Remove the SystemV.init script:

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/eGTouch.sh
```

Then enable the SystemD service you just created:

```
sudo systemctl enable eGTouch.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And at the end, restart it.

```
sudo systemctl restart eGTouch.service
```